How do I autobold parts of a cell in google sheets?
I am working on a program calendar for work, and need to bold alternating programs within the same cell. I have never used apps script before successfully, and am unsure of how to make it work.

Each cell with program names uses this formula to pull data from another sheet:
=JOIN(", ", IFERROR(QUERY(FILTER(Dates!$A$2:$A & " (" & Dates!$C$2:$C & ")",
(Dates!$D$2:$D = INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN()))) +
(Dates!$E$2:$E = INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN()))) +
(Dates!$F$2:$F = INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN()))) +
(Dates!$G$2:$G = INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN()))) +
(Dates!$H$2:$H = INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN()))) +
(Dates!$I$2:$I = INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN()))) +
(Dates!$J$2:$J = INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN()))) +
(Dates!$K$2:$K = INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN()))) +
(Dates!$L$2:$L = INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN()))) +
(Dates!$M$2:$M = INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN()))) +
(Dates!$N$2:$N = INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN())))),
"select Col1"), ""))

This gives an output of: Athletic U (4), Vex Iq (24), Master Builders (24), FYST (24). This is All given within one cell.
I would like to auto bold every other output so it would read: Athletic U (4), Vex Iq (24), Master Builders (24), FYST (24).
Is there a way to do this with apps script?
I tried to use chat GPT to write the apps script since I can't, but (shockingly) it didn't work.
T1
function alternateBoldText() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var values = range.getValue().split(',');
  var formattedValues = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      formattedValues.push(values[i]);
    } else {
      formattedValues.push(values[i].bold());
    }
  }
  
  var formattedString = formattedValues.join(', ');
  
  range.setValue(formattedString);
}


T2
=ISEVEN(ROUNDUP((LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ",", "")))/2,0))


T3
function alternateBoldTextInRange(range) {
  var output = [];
  range.forEach(function(row) {
    var bold = false;
    var cellValue = row[0];
    var segments = cellValue.split(',');
    var formattedSegments = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < segments.length; i++) {
      if (segments[i].trim() !== "") {
        formattedSegments.push(bold ? "<b>" + segments[i].trim() + "</b>" : segments[i].trim());
        bold = !bold;
      }
    }
    
    output.push([formattedSegments.join(', ')]);
  });
  
  return output;
}

was the best one to date, but it would return "Vex Go Racing (3), Lego Explorer (3)"

see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78592670/5632629 same way we can do bold instead of red but it will convert output of formula into plain text (eg. there wont be formula in that cell anymore)

Please don't add SOLVED to the question title. Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging. Please don't add the solution to the question body, Ref. [answer]. You might [edit] the question to explain why the solution on the linked question in the posted notice doesn't help you. This might help to reopen the question, and in such case you will be able to post your solution as an answer.
